# How to select Xml Data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

i woul like to select data from an xml api : the data look

```
<workzag-jobs>
<position>
<id>116303</id>
<recruitingCategory>Festangestellte</recruitingCategory>
<name>Initiativbewerbung (Festanstellung)</name>
<jobDescriptions>
<jobDescription>
<name>WAS DU MACHEN WIRST</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
<jobDescription>
<name>WAS DU MITBRINGST</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
<jobDescription>
<name>WAS WIR DIR BIETEN</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
</jobDescriptions>
<createdAt>2018-07-31T09:25:04+02:00</createdAt>
</position>
```

Now i  want to select with Javascript the "Jobdescription.name" and "Jobdescription.value" and than the second "jobdescription.name" and the "value" for the second time and so on..

**My Javascriptcode look like:**

```
var text = document.getElementById("jobsData");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://api.com/xml?language=de", false);
request.send();
var xml = request.responseXML;
var positions = xml.getElementsByTagName("position");
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    var position = positions[i];
    var dep = position.getElementsByTagName("department");
    var nam = position.getElementsByTagName("name");
    var id = position.getElementsByTagName("id");
    var office = position.getElementsByTagName("office");
    var JobDec = position.getElementsByTagName("value");

    for (var j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
        str += '<h1> ID: '+ id[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue +'</h1> <h3>Jobsdec : 
        '+JobDec[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</h3> <br> <input type="submit" 
        value="zur Job" id='+id[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue +' 
        onClick="reply(this.id)"  >';

    }
}

text.innerHTML = str;
```

can anyone help me? thanx in advance

Comment: You're iterating over the ID element—`<id>116303</id>`—wouldn't you want to iterate over the elements returned by `position.getElementsByTagName("jobDescription")` instead?

Comment: i get the ID but i wannt to get also the Job description Data (name and value) for the first time, second time and the third time. because each position has 3 job desciption with (names and values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your `xml` response to `DOM` using `DOMParser` and then you can use `querySelectorAll` to select `jobDescription` and iterate over it to get `name` and `value` elements within it.

```js
const str = `<workzag-jobs>
<position>
<id>116303</id>
<recruitingCategory>Festangestellte</recruitingCategory>
<name>Initiativbewerbung (Festanstellung)</name>
<jobDescriptions>
<jobDescription>
<name>WAS DU MACHEN WIRST</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
<jobDescription>
<name>WAS DU MITBRINGST</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
<jobDescription>
<name>WAS WIR DIR BIETEN</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
</jobDescriptions>
<createdAt>2018-07-31T09:25:04+02:00</createdAt>
</position>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');

doc.body.querySelectorAll('jobDescription').forEach((ele) => {
    const name = ele.querySelector('name').textContent;
    const val = ele.querySelector('value').textContent;
    console.log("Name :", name);
    console.log("Value :", val);
})
```

--- EDIT---

To get the `name` and `value` based on `id`, use `find` to get the `id`, get it's parent and then iterate over the `jobDescription` to get `name` and `value`.

```js
const str = `<workzag-jobs>
<position>
<id>116303</id>
<recruitingCategory>Festangestellte</recruitingCategory>
<name>Initiativbewerbung (Festanstellung)</name>
<jobDescriptions>
<jobDescription>
<name>WAS DU MACHEN WIRST</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
<jobDescription>
<name>WAS DU MITBRINGST</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
<jobDescription>
<name>WAS WIR DIR BIETEN</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
</jobDescriptions>
<createdAt>2018-07-31T09:25:04+02:00</createdAt>
</position>
<position>
<id>126073</id>
<recruitingCategory>Festangestellte</recruitingCategory>
<name>Initiativbewerbung (Festanstellung)</name>
<jobDescriptions>
<jobDescription>
<name>Deine Aufgaben</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
<jobDescription>
<name>Dein Profil</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
<jobDescription>
<name>Warum wir?</name>
<value>
<![CDATA[
<p style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p><ul style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);"><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</li><li>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</li><li>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li></ul>
]]>
</value>
</jobDescription>
</jobDescriptions>
<createdAt>2018-07-31T09:25:04+02:00</createdAt>
</position>
`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');

const searchId = "116303";

const filteredIdEle = Array.prototype.find.call(doc.body.querySelectorAll('*'), ((ele) => {
    return ele.textContent == searchId;
}));

if(filteredIdEle) {
    filteredIdEle.parentElement.querySelectorAll('jobDescription').forEach((ele) => {
        const name = ele.querySelector('name').textContent;
        const val = ele.querySelector('value').textContent;
        console.log("Name :", name);
        console.log("Value :", val);
    });
}
```

Comment: but how can i filter the data according to the ID, if i want for example only the names und values from ID: 116303

Comment: How you determine the `names` and `values` that are associated with `116303`?. I can see only single element `<id>116303</id>`.

Comment: the Api is too big i can not put all the content here, it consists of hundred position each Position has an ID und three Jobdescriptions and each Jobdescription has a name and value. can you help please to solve this Problem

Comment: Is there single `id` element within the `position` tag?

Comment: hier is a link for that Api https://iliass-jobs.personio.de/xml?language=de it only an example how it looks

Comment: yes each Position has only a unique ID but it consists of 3 jobsdescription und each jobdescription has a name and a value

Comment: @IliassHilmi - See edit. You can try changing the `searchId`.

Comment: it works very well thank so much!! i have only one last question how can i store the Xml Doc from the Api inside a Variable with the Http Protocole?